# react-router-dom v5 goBack work only when pressed twice

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In my app, I am trying to develop a back button. So, I implemented it like following.

```
<Button type="primary" className="primaryBtn btn__btn" shape="circle" icon={<ArrowLeftOutlined />} onClick={this.onPressGoBack} />
```

Then, for the onClick event I called this function.

```
onPressGoBack = () => {
    this.props.history.goBack();
}
```

Then, I exported the component like this.

```
export default withRouter(PageHeader);
```

But when I click the button, first time it doesn't do anything. Second time it navigates correctly. Am I doing anything wrong here. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: any errors on console?

Comment: No errors. But when I first press the button, this.props.history logged as {length: 11, action: "PUSH", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}. Second time it's like this. {length: 11, action: "POP", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}. I am not sure it has anything to do with it. But no errors.

Comment: Did you somehow PUSH two entries onto the history stack, so it takes two POP actions to *actually* go back? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've got the same problem. A `PUSH` first and then a `POP`. Did you find a solution in the end?